# How to set default bad layers handler in the python plugin?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I am trying to write a python plugin for QGis. My python plugin will copy a template qgis project into data catalog with ESRI shapefiles. Because data catalogs can vary in its content there will be possibility that in the output catalog may be less layers than in the project template.
Is it possible to set default bad layer handler inside python plugin every time when I load programmatically copied project form output catalog?
I am new in programming qgis plugin and I suppose that I should use something like that:

```
proj = QgsProject.instance()
handler = proj.setBadLayerHandler() #I don't know what kind of arguments I should put in this method.
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QgsProjectBadLayerHandler](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsProjectBadLayerHandler.html) is an abstract base class. You have to create a derived class, create an instance from this and pass this instance to the QgsProject.
Within your derived class, implement your logic in the handleBadLayers( domNodes, domDocument ) method.

A very short example:

```
# this is the derived class
class MyBadLayerHandler( QgsProjectBadLayerHandler ):
    def __init__( self ):
        QgsProjectBadLayerHandler.__init__( self )

    # this is the method that will be called to handle bad layers
    def handleBadLayers( self, domNodes, domDocument ):
        print( 'oops, bad layer!' )

# this is your instance of your handler
myBadLayerHandler = MyBadLayerHandler()
# finally assign the handler
QgsProject.instance().setBadLayerHandler( myBadLayerHandler )
```

Comment: I have already used myBadLayerHandler(QgsProjectBadLayerDefaultHandler): in the same way as you suggested. I'm not sure, that is a good way. In my plugin it works first time, next time Qgis alwayes crashes. I think this a result of my lack of experience in the advanced programming using an abstract base classes. I will try to do this in the next version of plugin. Current version will use the default qgis prompt gui bad layer handler.  Thanks!

Comment: You should call `QgsProjectBadLayerHandler.__init__(self)` in `def __init__`

Comment: There is one tiny difference between 1.8 and 2.0: With 1.8 you kept ownership of the bad layer handler. That means, you have to make sure, you keep a reference to it somewhere in your plugin code, so it does not get deleted. This could be the source of your crash. With 2.0 this will not be necessary any more.

Comment: I use  `QgsProjectBadLayerDefaultHandler.__init__(self) in def __init__` of plugin. Inside plugin I create derived class for bad layer handler  `class myBadLayerHandler(QgsProjectBadLayerDefaultHandler):
             def handleBadLayers(self, domNodes, domDocument ):
                print( 'bad layer!' )`   and after that in code I use `self.mBadLayerHandler = pluginDialog.myBadLayerHandler()            QgsProject.instance().setBadLayerHandler(self.mBadLayerHandler)` It works properly once. Do you have any idea what I should correct

Comment: Which version do you have?

Comment: My plugin should work in version 1.7.4 and 1.8, so I am developing it in this environment

Comment: Do you have your code available somewhere? Reading your question again: You don't have to replace the handler every time. Just once, it will be called repeatedly. And then make sure, you always keep a reference to it somewhere in your plugin.

Comment: Thank you very myuch @Matthias Kuhn. Your explanations about replacing a handler, helped me. I moved  `QgsProject.instance().setBadLayerHandler(mBadLayerHandler)` to the main python file of plugin to the method  def run(self): and it works. Thank you!