# QGIS BadLayerHandler - setDataProvider()

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I've made a bit of a plugin to handle badlayers (I'm aware that Change datasource plugin had something for this but the code appears to have been removed now?). I've followed the advice provided in [How to set default bad layers handler in the python plugin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67291/how-to-set-default-bad-layers-handler-in-the-python-plugin) and I can get the handler to start when layers are missing.

I'm currently having trouble setting the new data provider. Currently I'm doing

```
handler = QgsProjectbadLayerHandler()

newPath = "C:\pathtomissinglayer"

handler.setDataSource(domNode,newPath)
```

where `domNode` has been passed in from `handleBadLayers(self, domNodes)`

This doesn't work as expected. The layers still disappear and setting the data source doesn't seem to change anything even though it executes properly.
Should I be passing in the `newPath` as a string or something else? And how do I stop the layers from disappearing?

Edit: There appears to be a new class as a part of 3.6?? called [QgsStoreBadLayerInfo](https://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsStoreBadLayerInfo.html#aeac2082332d23a68574f1f4ced683432). Description says it stores layer IDs of bad layers. The ID could be useful to get the position of the map layer in the layer explorer and then just create a new layer with the correct file path. As is extends from QgsProjectBadLayerHandler could this class just be used in place of QgsProjectBadLayerHandler? Will it be called when layers are missing? I tried but couldn't get it too work

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit late, but for reference:

The `setDataSource` method of `QgsProjectBadLayerHandler` seem to only update the passed `QDOMNode` instance. To actually load the layer from the new data source, call `readLayer` method of `QgsProject`, passing the same `QDOMNode` instance that was passed to `setDataSource`.

Eg. after the approach that OP outlined, call

```
QgsProject.instance().readLayer(domNode)
```

in the plugin code.

There is also a short refenence to this in the [QGIS Python API Documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html?highlight=qgsproject#qgis.core.QgsProject.readLayer).