# PyQGIS startup script - remove bad layers

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm using the startup code option in QGIS ([described here](https://madmanwoo.gitlab.io/foss4g-python-workshop/startup/)) to load a .QGS library and execute python scripting.

I've used [this method](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67291/how-to-set-default-bad-layers-handler-in-the-python-plugin) to ignore bad layers when starting QGIS and loading the library and it usually works fine.

The issue i'm having is occasionally, not with any consistency, i will get a python error noting that DomDocument cant be found and pauses the script.

**TypeError: handleBadLayers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'domDocument'**

Does anyone know how to get around this, really all we need is to ignore bad layers and not throw an error so the code can run 'hands off'.

This is the first part of the startup script im trying to run:

```
##import processing modules

# necessary imports
import os
import sys
import json
import shutil
import pandas as pd
import PyQt5.QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import *
from qgis import utils
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
from pathlib import Path


# initializing processing module
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis() # use qgs.exitQgis() to exit the processing module at the end of the script.

# initialize processing algorithms
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
#set action for Bad Layers
# this is the derived class
class MyBadLayerHandler(QgsProjectBadLayerHandler): 

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    # This is the method that will be called to handle bad layers
    def handleBadLayers(self, domNodes, domDocument):
        if domDocument is not None:
            print('Oops, bad layer!')

# This is your instance of your handler
myBadLayerHandler = MyBadLayerHandler()

# Finally assign the handler
QgsProject.instance().setBadLayerHandler(myBadLayerHandler)

project = QgsProject.instance
#Load Project
QgsProject.instance().read('//corp.ads/gis/example.qgs')
```